# Basic use of server side API and passing server side variable to client side

Tags: node.js, npm-install, serverside-javascript

I've just started my IT degree and I'm a beginner to the use of APIs (and forums like this) so I am truly sorry if my question is to vaguely explained or if it is just plain stupid :), on top of that I'm not a native English speaker :P. Okay, so I'm trying to use Google trends' api which I installed in my server with putty by using sudo npm install google-trends-api. (it can be found here https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-trends-api#installation) As I undestand it, this is a server side api so the scripts that I write with the methods provided for this api will not run on an explorer as normal js files do. There is an example that makes use of the API that I found on the page which is as follows

```
var googleTrends = requite('google-trends-api');

googleTrends.hotTrends('US')
.then(function(results){
    console.log(results);
})
.catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

this outputs a list of 20 items on the console when I use it on node.
I would like to know if there is a way to assign those results to a variable and then use that variable in a normal javascript script inside a html file. I do not know anything about node.js and the like, and I would like to actually do some research instead of asking here but I was going to use a different approach to acquire such information but now I've had to change my plans and do not have enough time and given I consider this is a fairly easy problem to resolve (maybe?) I would really appreciate it if someone could walk me through the basics of each step. THanks :) and have a nice day.

Comment: OK, since you are just starting I would like to point you in the following direction, check out https://expressjs.com, which is a simple framework to build websites, where you have the front-end (html) part, and the back-end (what you just wrote) structured for you. Plus go to YouTube, and search for "ExpressJS tutorial", watch few of those videos, and you should have a good grasp of how to go about building websites using NodeJS. Have fun learning .

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite broad. Node.js is Chrome's V8 engine bundled with some libraries to do I/O and networking. This enables us to JavaScript outside of the browser and to create backend services or servers in general (in your case). I hope that you are aware of this difference :)

The first thing that you have to do, is to have a look at express.js and to create a simple server. It will not be more than 20 lines of code. Then you have to enrich this with more stuff like a template engine (handlebars.js, jade etc). You have to enable the server to serve static files that will be finally your js, css and image files. Creating this simple server you will be able to serve simple html page in the first place. On top of that you should have the client side javascript that you have to write and now you can use the module above. Unfortunately, you are not able to use this module directly on a javascript file that you will write. To be able to use this module you have to transcompile this thing into javascript that browser understand*. Remember that browser does not understand the require statement and some old browsers possibly will have issues with the promises that this module is using. These are the things that should be compiled. You have to use a tool like browserify for this and the compiled file that this will extract it must be included in the scripts of your html page.

Maybe there are quite a lot of concepts that you are not aware of or you don't understand them but spend a bit of time to understand them.

P.S.: I' ve replied under the assumption that `google-trends-api` module does not use things that are specific to node.js like the file-system for example.